# How to get numbers from pushed array

Tags: javascript

I want to get numbers from an array. At first I collect the numbers, after I want to get the sum of these numbers.
But I can not, how to use `split` here? Maybe split is not necessary here.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("myInp");
input.addEventListener("blur", getValues);

var num = document.getElementById("myNum");

var result = document.getElementById("result");
var sumBtn = document.getElementById("sumBtn");
sumBtn.addEventListener("click", getSum);

var arr = [];

function getValues() {
  arr.push(input.value);
  num.innerHTML = arr;
}


function getSum() {
  result.innerHTML = 0;
  arr.split(",");

  result.innerHTML = parseFloat(result.innerHTML) + arr;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInp">
<button id="myBtn">Start</button>

<p id="myNum"></p>

<button id="sumBtn">Getsum</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Start with checking console for errors "TypeError: arr.split is not a function" Not only "split is not necessary here" it cause an error because arrays do not have `split` method.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko because Marie needed a `join` instead

Comment: @mplungjan Even call to `join` woudn't help to "get the sum of these numbers" :)

Comment: But it would not error out. See my answer for the complete solution inclusive a sum

Answer (score 0):

You mean [arr.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join). And you need a [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) too AND convert to number

Assuming you want to enter one number at a time, then the code could look like this:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("myInp"),
  but = document.getElementById("myBtn"),
  num = document.getElementById("myNum"),
  result = document.getElementById("result"),
  sumBtn = document.getElementById("sumBtn");

but.addEventListener("click", getValues);
sumBtn.addEventListener("click", getSum);

var arr = [];

function getValues() {
  var val = +input.value // make it a number before pushing
  if (!isNaN(val)) {
    arr.push(val); 
  }  
  input.focus(); 
  input.select();
  num.innerHTML = arr;
}


function getSum() {
  result.innerHTML = arr.join("+") + "=" + 
    arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0); // the reduce will sum the numbers
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInp">
<button id="myBtn">Start</button>

<p id="myNum"></p>

<button id="sumBtn">Getsum</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

If you want to enter comma delimited numbers then try this:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("myInp"),
  but = document.getElementById("myBtn"),
  num = document.getElementById("myNum"),
  result = document.getElementById("result"),
  sumBtn = document.getElementById("sumBtn");

but.addEventListener("click", getValues);
sumBtn.addEventListener("click", getSum);

var arr = [];

function getValues() {
  arr.push(input.value);
  input.focus();
  input.select();
  num.innerHTML = arr;
}


function getSum() {
  console.log(arr)
  arr.forEach(function(nums) {
    if (nums) {
      var thisArr = nums.split(",")
      result.innerHTML += thisArr.join("+") + "=" +
        thisArr.reduce((a, b) => +a + +b, 0) + "<br/>"; // the reduce will sum the numbers
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInp" placeholder="for ex. 1,2,3">
<button id="myBtn">Start</button>

<p id="myNum"></p>

<button id="sumBtn">Getsum</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code

```js
    var input = document.getElementById("myInp");
    input.addEventListener("blur", getValues);

    var num = document.getElementById("myNum");

    var result = document.getElementById("result");
    var sumBtn = document.getElementById("sumBtn");
    sumBtn.addEventListener("click", getSum);



    var arr = [];

    function getValues(){
     arr.push(input.value);
     num.innerHTML = arr;
    }


    function getSum(){
     result.innerHTML = 0;
     let data = arr[0].split(",");
     let sum = data.reduce((sum,val)=>{return sum + parseFloat(val);},0)
     result.innerHTML = sum;
    }
```

```html
    <input type="text" id="myInp">
    <button id="myBtn">Start</button>

    <p id="myNum"></p>

    <button id="sumBtn">Getsum</button>
    <p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Why do you split the first value and reduce it? See my code for a working version. AHH you want to enter `1,2,5` instead of `1 enter 2 enter 5`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var input = document.getElementById("myInp");
input.addEventListener("blur", getValues);

var num = document.getElementById("myNum");

var result = document.getElementById("result");
var sumBtn = document.getElementById("sumBtn");
sumBtn.addEventListener("click", getSum);

var arr = [];

function getValues() {
  arr.push(input.value);
  num.innerHTML = arr;
}


function getSum() {
  result.innerHTML = 0; 

  result.innerHTML = arr.reduce((a, x) => +a + +x);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInp">
<button id="myBtn">Start</button>

<p id="myNum"></p>

<button id="sumBtn">Getsum</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to type each number one by one. I wrote this piece of code as an example of what you might want.

**I removed the start button and made it so when you click Enter it adds to the array.** (the start button purpose, I think, was to add numbers to the array. A bit redundant given you already had the "blur" eventListener).

I also changed the input type from **text** to **number** to give it less chance to fail.

```js
var arr = [];
var input = $('#myInp');
var num = $('#myNum');
var sumBtn = $('#sumBtn');
var result = $('#result');


input.keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    getValues(this);
    input.val("");
  }
});

sumBtn.click(function(){
 result.text(arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0))
})

function getValues(e) {
  arr.push( parseInt(input.val()));
  $('#myNum').text(arr.join(" + "));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="myInp">

<p id="myNum"></p>

<button id="sumBtn">Getsum</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```